# Prevent all processes to write on /var

Tags: linux, init

I would like to move the `/var` folder of my server (xen server) to a new disk.
I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131311/moving-var-home-to-separate-partition#answer-131318) but the `init 1` command log me out from the ssh session.

Also can I avoid using `init 1` to prevent all process to write in this folder ?
Instead I think I can try to stop all running services and check with `lsof | grep /var` that there is no open file on `/var` before I move it.

Is it a proper way to do this ?

Comment: As a workaround I've add the single-user run level the ssh service run levels. Change both of this lines in `/etc/init/ssh.conf`:
`start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]`
by those:
`start on runlevel [S2345]
stop on runlevel [!S2345]`
After this changes done, you will be able to log back to your ssh session, once ejected by the `init 1` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it properly, you need to access your server locally and put it in single-user mode. Stopping services one by one via `ssh` will not help since `ssh` is itself a service and it's also using `/var`, e.g. for logging in `/var/log/secure`.